# certain lines to print

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
all_courses=open("E:/we/aa.txt","r").readlines()
completed_ones=open("E:/we/aaa.txt","r")
read_completed_ones=completed_ones.readlines()
for ankosh in read_completed_ones:
       the_big=ankosh


for line in all_courses:
    splitted=line.split(",")
    the_max_number=len(splitted)

    if the_max_number>2:
        courses_remaining=splitted[2]
        courses_remaining_splitted=courses_remaining.split("|")

        if courses_remaining_splitted==['']:
            print courses_remaining_splitted
                ankosh2=splitted[0]
```

i want to print a program that when i give completed courses of college and then the remaining courses and the ones i'm allowed to take, but i get stuck and dont know how to continue, i want to print the line that contains [""] ,as the courses_remaining_splitted[2], and the courses_remaining_splitted[0] doesn't equal any of the completed courses so it could fall under the dict "courses allowed to take". go easy newbie, any weird codes feel free to comment, i like learning from code mistakes :)
appreciate the help

sample of completed courses :
http://ranger.uta.edu/~kamangar/CSE-1310-FA13/LinkedDocuments/sample_completed_courses.txt

all courses:
http://ranger.uta.edu/~kamangar/CSE-1310-FA13/LinkedDocuments/required_courses.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib2

completed_courses_url = 'http://ranger.uta.edu/~kamangar/CSE-1310-FA13/LinkedDocuments/sample_completed_courses.txt'
required_courses_url = 'http://ranger.uta.edu/~kamangar/CSE-1310-FA13/LinkedDocuments/required_courses.csv'

completed_courses_set = set([x.strip() for x in urllib2.urlopen(completed_courses_url)])
for required_course in urllib2.urlopen(required_courses_url):
    if required_course[0] != '#':
        (course,category,prerequisites,notes) = required_course.split(',')
        if set(prerequisites.split('|')).intersection(completed_courses_set):
             print required_course
```

$ python test.py

MATH 1426,preprofessional,MATH 1323,

MATH 2425,preprofessional,MATH 1426,

PHYS 1443,preprofessional,MATH 1426,

CSE 1320,preprofessional,CSE 1104|CSE 1105|CSE 1310|MATH 1323,

CSE 2315,preprofessional,CSE 1310|MATH 1426,

IE 3312,professional,MATH 1426,

MATH 3330,professional,MATH 1426,

Comment: but how to use it from an opened file ?